# Matlab lsqnonlin Fit Problems with Options

Tags: matlab, solver, model-fitting

Pretty sure Matlab is just ignoring my Solver Option settings... I'm setting the `FuctionTolerance` from the default `1e-6` to `1e-10` and the solver is stopping at `1e-8` telling me it's below the default `1e-6` limit.

The command I am using is `options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin', 'FunctionTolerance', 1e-10)`. Any ideas?

Command window output below:

```
options = 

  lsqnonlin options:

   Options used by current Algorithm ('trust-region-reflective'):
   (Other available algorithms: 'levenberg-marquardt')

   Set properties:
           FunctionTolerance: 1.0000e-10

   Default properties:
                   Algorithm: 'trust-region-reflective'
              CheckGradients: 0
                     Display: 'final'
    FiniteDifferenceStepSize: 'sqrt(eps)'
        FiniteDifferenceType: 'forward'
         JacobianMultiplyFcn: []
      MaxFunctionEvaluations: '100*numberOfVariables'
               MaxIterations: 400
         OptimalityTolerance: 1.0000e-06
                   OutputFcn: []
                     PlotFcn: []
    SpecifyObjectiveGradient: 0
               StepTolerance: 1.0000e-06
         SubproblemAlgorithm: 'factorization'
                    TypicalX: 'ones(numberOfVariables,1)'
                 UseParallel: 0


Local minimum possible.

lsqnonlin stopped because the final change in the sum of squares relative to 
its initial value is less than the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>

Optimization stopped because the relative sum of squares (r) is changing
by less than options.FunctionTolerance = 1.000000e-06.

Optimization Metric                                  Options
relative change r =   6.50e-08             FunctionTolerance =   1e-06 (default)
```

Comment: `FunctionTolerance` is not an option for `lsqnonlin`. Use `TolFun` instead

Comment: That doesn't work. From what I can see it's synonymous.

Comment: Is that `1E-8` value the function value, step size, maximum gradient norm, or something else? [There are several values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html) that can stop the iterations.

Comment: @Troy I had changed everything and got the same problem. I have realised what the issue is now... I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command `options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin', 'FunctionTolerance', 1e-10)` does not itself change the settings.

`options` is a variable that has some setting parameters in it and has to be passed into the function call to actively change the parameters.

`optimisedParameters = lsqnonlin(functionToMinimise, initialParameters, [], [], options)`

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing `FiniteDifferenceStepSize`, e.g.,

```
options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin', 'FunctionTolerance', 1e-10, 'FiniteDifferenceStepSize',1e-6)
```

or even smaller Finite Difference Step Size.